# Pass variable into php web form from android app

Tags: php, android

I have the following php snippet. I am working on an android program and need to somehow pass in the 'pid'. How can I do this so that it will return the form with the given pid? Can I do this without passing in a parameter using a POST request?

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['resp']) == "success")
    {
        echo '<div class="success-box" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 20px;">Success</div>';
    }
    else {
        require_once('connect.php');
        $pid = $_SESSION['pid'];

        $qry1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE pid = '$pid'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($qry1) > 0)
        {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($qry1);

...

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use hidden variable in your form

`<input type="hidden" id="pid" name="pid" value="give the value" />`

and use it like

`$pid = $_POST['pid']`